# Relationship between homological functors and t-structures

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Let $D$ be a triangulated category, $A$ an abelian category and $\pi: D \to A$ a homological functor (sending distinguished triangles to long exact sequences). Can we describe (the) obstructions to finding

a) A triangulated category $D'$ with a t-structure on it and heart $A$, and a triangle functor $\alpha: D \to D'$ such that $\pi = \pi' \alpha$, where $\pi'$ is the canonical functor associated to the t-structure

b) same as a), but with $D'=D(A)$ (and the canonical t structure)?

I have no particular motivation for this, just general curiosity how these concepts relate.

Taking $D$ to be the stable homotopy category and $\pi$ the usual (stable) homotopy groups shows that b) is not always possible.  I don't know about a).

If D is suitably large, I think a version of brown representability should apply (in some cases), potentially allowing us to assume that $\pi$ is representable. Not sure if this helps.